# Asymptotic cumulative distributive function

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d ~$ Unif (-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ and $S_n= \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Let $a \in \mathbb{R}: \frac{1}{n} \leq a \leq \frac{2}{n}$

My aim is to:

1) Find the asymptotic behavior of the following cumulative distributive function:
$$
p_n= P\bigg(\bigg|\frac{S_n}{\sqrt n}\bigg| \leq \frac{1}{a\sqrt n}- \frac{\sqrt n}{2}   \bigg)
$$
2) Find $a$ that maximizes $p_n$.

Through Central Limit theorem and using Berry-Essen theorem, I'm only able to find the upper bound for $p_n$.

Can we characterize the lower bound as well ?
I believe $p_n$ behaves as $\Theta(1/\sqrt n)$

Comment: @Did: Yeah, the bounds are the same. Because you can see that at $a=\frac{2}{n}, \frac{1}{a\sqrt n}-\frac{\sqrt n}{2}=0.$

Comment: Right, thanks for the remark.

Comment: Rereading the question, I find it most bizarre: obviously, $p_n$ is minimal when $a$ is maximal, that is, when $a=\frac2n$, and then $p_n=0$ for every $n$, and $p_n$ is maximal when $a$ is minimal, that is, when $a=\frac1n$, and then $p_n=P\left(\left|\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right|\leqslant\frac12\sqrt{n}\right)$ hence $p_n\to1$ when $n\to\infty$. To tell you the truth, all this strongly hints at some mistakes in the copying process of the question...